# How are rpm transactions used in `yum update`?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, rpm

Is the whole `yum update` transactional or is every resolved update individually?

If the `yum update` detects `Foo` and `Bar` need to be updated, and `Bar` fails because it now collides with installed package `Baz`, does `Foo` get updated? Does the transaction include `yum update Foo` and `yum update Bar` independent of each other, or `yum update`?

If `Foo` doesn't get updated by default, is there an easy way to make it get updated regardless of failures of other parts of system update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole update is currently using one transaction. You can skip broken packages from being scheduled inside that transaction use `--skip-broken` or `SKIP_BROKEN=1` in the `yum.conf`. You can see the list of the yum transacations using, `yum history`,

```
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    23 | centos <centos>          | 2019-07-10 10:24 | Update         |   19
```

The transactions will show up as Action = Update.